# Angular slice ( | slice:0:10 ) not working when slicing Django API result

Tags: angular, typescript, api, slice, ngfor

I'm trying to slice a Django API response with 50 results to only show 10 results and the code below doesn't seem to work.  The error:

```
(variable) post: unknown
Object is of type 'unknown'.
```

Without the pipe, it displays 50 results.

```
<div class="news-row news-row-link" *ngFor="let post of Posts['results'] | slice:0:10">
      <div class="news-cells">
        <a href="{{ post['link'] }}" class="news-cell nc-date">
          <span>
            <time datetime="" title="Sun Sep 26 2021">{{ post['pub_date'] | timeAgo }}</time> <!---->
          </span>
          <!---->
        </a>
        <!----> 
        <a href="{{ post['link'] }}" class="news-cell nc-title">
          <span class="title-text">
            <!---->
            <span>{{ post['title'] }}</span>
          </span>
          <!---->
        </a>
        <!----> <!----> <!---->
      </div>
  </div>
```

My component.ts

```
  Posts:any = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllPosts();
  }

  getAllPosts(){
    this.service.getAllPosts().subscribe(data=>{
      this.Posts = data;
    })
  }
```

My API Service

```
export class APIService {

  readonly BaseAPI = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/'

  constructor( private http:HttpClient ) { }

  getAllPosts():Observable<any[]>{
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.BaseAPI + 'posts/');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using async pipe to show the lates updated version of Post so that's why the html only sees the first value which is empty;

Post: any = []; (is empty)

Use BehaviorSubjects to subscribe the new value and then use async in html to update the html. You can learn about [AsyncPipe here](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe.

Change your code to this

`Post: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject(null);`

then when you get values from your service just push to Post

`this.Post.next(data);`

and then in your html you can show the latest emitted value using async pipe

`*ngFor="let post of (Posts['results'] | async) | slice:0:10"`

cheers.

Comment: im getting an error on `Post: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject(null);` as `Type 'BehaviorSubject<null>' is not assignable to type 'BehaviorSubject<any[]>'. Types of property 'value' are incompatible. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.`